# RxJava 3 support for Room

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, rx-java3

I am using RxJava3 with Room in my project but I am getting the following error

error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable>)

Below is DAO interface method on which I am getting the error

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM wishlist_table")
Flowable<List<WishListMovie>> getWishList();
```

I think maybe its because I am using the dependency below in my grade file:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
```

I tried to find the above dependency for RxJava 3 but I was unable to find it.

I want to know how can I use RxJava 3 with Room or should I use RxJava 2 instead in my project.

Answer (score 8):

**July 22, 2020**

In [Room 2.3.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0-alpha02) was added support for RxJava3 types.
Though it's still in alpha, but you can consider this option.

According to release description:

> Similar to RxJava2 you can declare DAO methods whose return type are
> Flowable, Single, Maybe and Completable.
> Additionally a new artifact
> `androidx.room:room-rxjava3` is available to support RxJava3

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

> I want to know how can I use RxJava 3 with Room or should I use RxJava 2 instead in my project.

## Result

You can not use RxJava3 with Room "room-rxjava2" dependency.

## Explanation

RxJava2 and RxJava3 are different. In order to avoid runtime errors (e.g. during linking) RxJava3 chose different packages. This is why the returned type does not match (different package)

## Solution

Until there is a room-rxjava3 package you have to use RxJava2 as a dependency.

## Workaround

You could checkout room-rxjava2 and change all packages for rxjava3 and compile aginst rxjava3 and then use this package.

Answer (score 2):

Currently updating a project and having the same problem.

I'm using room-rxjava2 to generate the DAOs (as before) with RxJava2 types.
But for my business logic I'm using https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaBridge to convert to RxJava3 types.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be not using a reactive type on the Dao and have a reactive wrapper it in a repository